# NSDate from week number

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nscalendar

I am trying to create a weekly recurring local notification using Swift. Notification is going to be set to first day of every week, and in 10:00. Ofcourse I don't want to set a notification for a past date, so I need to see if now it has passed first day of week 10:00. If not, I will create notification for today 10:00, else next week monday 10:00.

I created an extension to calculate week number for current date.

```
    extension NSDate {

        func weekOfYear() -> Int {
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear, fromDate: self)
        let weekOfYear = components.weekOfYear

        return weekOfYear
        }
    }
```

I couldn't go any further than this. Any help is appreciated.
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easier solution to your problem. You can use the `nextDateAfterDate()` method of `NSCalendar`:

```
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let comps = NSDateComponents()
comps.hour = 10
comps.weekday = cal.firstWeekday

let now = NSDate()
let fireDate = cal.nextDateAfterDate(now, matchingComponents: comps, options: [.MatchNextTimePreservingSmallerUnits])!
```

This gives the first date in the future which is at 10:00 on the first day of the week.

Comment: Thank you for the fast and easy solution. How about if I want to set fireDate to next first day of the month?

Comment: @ErkanA: `comps.day = 1` instead of `comps.weekday = cal.firstWeekday` should do the trick. – Isn't that obvious? :)

Comment: I think I have written a little confusing. I need to find next occurrence for "first day of month 10:00" (monthly notification)

Comment: @ErkanA: Yes, and with `comps.hour = 10; comps.day = 1` you should get that result.

Comment: I just tested and understood. Excuse me for being late, I am on my first project and it's clear that I need to learn a lot more about NSCalendar. Thank you